# Android PreferenceFragment, best practice for persistent UI update?

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-sharedpreferences

I am implementing the Settings for my android app through the `PreferenceFragment`. 
My `android:summary` for the different Preferences should display the current value at all times therefore I have read through severals posts and the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#Listening).
Although I got it working technically my solution seems kind of hacky and I am now searching for best practice since I found no good source on how it is meant to be properly implemented.

For example I implemented `onSharedPreferenceChanged` to listen for changes and to update the UI, but after every restart of the `PreferenceFragment`, the initial `android:summary` is shown again. To solve this I added this to the `onCreate`

```
// display current value in the UI 
EditTextPreference editText = (EditTextPreference) findPreference("serverAddress"); 
editText.setSummary(editText.getText());
```

Is this is how it is supposed to be done or am I misunderstanding something ?

Full Code:

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    public static final String KEY_PREF_SERVER_ADDRESS = "serverAddress";
    public static final String KEY_PREF_GENDER = "gender";

    public SettingsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
        //Load the preferences from the XML file
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

        // display current value in the UI
        EditTextPreference editText = (EditTextPreference) findPreference("serverAddress");
        editText.setSummary(editText.getText());

    }

    // Listen for settings changes and update the UI
    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        if (key.equals(KEY_PREF_SERVER_ADDRESS)) {
            Preference serverAddressPref = findPreference(key);
            //Set UI to display updated summary
            serverAddressPref.setSummary(sharedPreferences.getString(key, ""));
        }
        if (key.equals(KEY_PREF_GENDER)) {
            Preference serverAddressPref = findPreference(key);
            //Set UI to display updated summary
            serverAddressPref.setSummary(sharedPreferences.getString(key, ""));
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences()
                .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences()
                .unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: From what I can see, you are using the best practice. Setting the preferences' summary programmatically is what I've always seen and done.

Comment: I am just irritated by the fact that in the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#Listening) where they talk about how to use setSummary for a Preference, they dont mention that one has to set it in the onCreate of the Fragment every time additionally. Therefore I thought it is more likely that I am misunderstanding some concept.

Comment: No worries. Sometimes I've found that their examples/documentation left much unanswered. That being said though, I've seen numerous tutorials that declare setSummary in the onCreate but also use an "if" statement to ensure there is a default summary. Check [this](http://www.feelzdroid.com/2015/06/android-preferencefragment-settings-screen-implementation.html)

Comment: do you call `PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(context, R.xml.preferences, false);` anywhere? this is supposed to correctly initialise the user prefs.